# Proper forward definition in C++ file for C include

Tags: c++, c

I have the following code that throws a compile error when compiling `x.cpp` (`conflicting declaration 'typedef struct THE_TYPE_STRUCT THE_TYPE'`, on last line in `y.h`, g++ 5.3.0):

```
// x.h file
struct THE_TYPE;

class C{
        THE_TYPE * t;    
};

// x.cpp file
#include "x.h"

extern "C"{
#include "y.h"
}

// y.h file
struct THE_TYPE_STRUCT {
    int x;
};

typedef struct THE_TYPE_STRUCT THE_TYPE;
```

File `y.h` is a C header that can not be included at the beginning of the header `x.h` because of conflicting names with other header files, so I have to make a forward definition for `THE_TYPE`. Seems that it's not completely properly. **How do I do it properly?**

Comment: It seems you are in control of the files, `x.h` and `x.cpp`. I would suggest you use a `namespace`

Comment: You should show a real example. We can only guess what is happening

Comment: `extern "C"` also needs to be applied to declarations, not just definitions.     Change `x.h` to contain `extern "C" {struct THE_TYPE_STRUCT;}  class C {THE_TYPE_STRUCT *t};`.    No reliance on the `typedef` in `x.h`, since the C++ compiler never sees it.

Answer (score 1):

C is not the same as C++ and have different rules (for example, `typedef struct THE_TYPE THE_TYPE;` is useless -since implicit- in C++ but meaningful in C).

You should generate the preprocessed form (e.g. with `g++ -C -E x.cpp > x.ii`) then study it. A possible trick is to remove line information (starting with `#`) by running 
 `g++ -C -E x.cpp | grep -v '^#' > x.ii` then recompile using `g++ -Wall -c x.ii` and look into the faulty locations in `x.ii`

Without knowing the actual files involved, we cannot help (e.g. perhaps some file has some `#define THE_TYPE`).

> How do I do it properly?

In C++, you'll probably use `namespace`-s (notably in your own files) and avoid macros.

In C, you probably should edit your files, and I suggest to add a common prefix to every public name in your own code. You might take inspiration from [GTK](http://gtk.org/) where every name is starting with `Gtk` or `GTK` or `_GTK` etc...

In general you need some consistent naming conventions and you probably need to edit *all* your files.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
struct THE_TYPE_STRUCT {
    int x;
};

typedef struct THE_TYPE_STRUCT THE_TYPE;
```

to

```
typedef struct THE_TYPE_STRUCT {
    int x;
}THE_TYPE;
```

Comment: This probably won't work if some `struct THE_TYPE_STRUCT` has already been defined.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following scheme in my current project mixing a bit of [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) code into a [c11](/questions/tagged/c11) codebase:

**basedecl.h** (included everywhere):

```c
// [...]
#ifdef __cplusplus
#  define pocaslibs___cdecl extern "C"
#  define DECLDATA
#  define C_CLASS_DECL(t) struct t
#  define C_ENUM_DECL(t) enum t
#else
#  define pocaslibs___cdecl
#  define DECLDATA extern
#  define C_CLASS_DECL(t) typedef struct t t
#  define C_ENUM_DECL(t) typedef enum t t
#endif
// [...]
```

Forward-declaring `struct` types (also used for "private" types):

```
C_CLASS_DECL(PG_Menu);
C_CLASS_DECL(PG_Window);
```

Declaring "public" `struct` types:

```
C_CLASS_DECL(PG_Bounds);
struct PG_Bounds
{
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
};
```

Works quite nicely for both languages. The macro is named `C_CLASS_DECL` because in my codebase, this is really used for creating OO classes in [c](/questions/tagged/c). If your usecase has nothing to do with OO, better think about a better name ;)